# What does "people without substance" mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context

https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/be%20without%20substance

> We tend to dismiss stories as the last resort of people without **substance**. As an older retiree remarked, “Why, I have a perfect memory. I even remember things that never happened.” We denigrate professors and elders for telling “war stories.”

[Source](https://books.google.com.vn/books?id=iRArDwAAQBAJ&pg=PA247&lpg=PA247&dq=We%20tend%20to%20dismiss%20stories%20as%20the%20last%20resort%20of%20people%20without%20substance.%20As%20an%20older%20retiree%20remarked,%20%E2%80%9CWhy,%20I%20have%20a%20perfect%20memory.%20I%20even%20remember%20things%20that%20never%20happened.%E2%80%9D%20We%20denigrate%20professors%20and%20elders%20for%20telling%20%E2%80%9Cwar%20stories.%E2%80%9D&source=bl&ots=oxN1vdAm_T&sig=ACfU3U24nAyG-OZGzZFmLiIdSv3lyJbuZA&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwig58Tz1cnhAhVQPHAKHTLyAioQ6AEwAHoECAAQAQ#v=onepage&q=We%20tend%20to%20dismiss%20stories%20as%20the%20last%20resort%20of%20people%20without%20substance.%20As%20an%20older%20retiree%20remarked%2C%20%E2%80%9CWhy%2C%20I%20have%20a%20perfect%20memory.%20I%20even%20remember%20things%20that%20never%20happened.%E2%80%9D%20We%20denigrate%20professors%20and%20elders%20for%20telling%20%E2%80%9Cwar%20stories.%E2%80%9D&f=false).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The argument in that paragraph is that "*WE*" make the mistake of thinking such people (e.g. professors and elders) are '*without substance*', which means they are ***without enough intellectual capacity to present the idea directly***.